# Cannot get any data against a Austria user with Huawei Health kit

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have a user(in Austria) who sent images of his account with the cloud being enabled, etc.  However, when I did a request against his account, I couldn’t see any data -- its similar to what my US account showed.

For example, during this time period, he showed a run:

```
{"group":[ { "startTime":1611288803278, "endTime":1611893603278, "sampleSet":[ { "dataCollectorId":"derived:com.huawei.continuous.steps.delta:com.huawei.hwid:merged", "samplePoints":[ ] } ] }, { "startTime":1611288803278, "endTime":1611893603278, "sampleSet":[ { "dataCollectorId":"derived:com.huawei.continuous.distance.delta:com.huawei.hwid:merged", "samplePoints":[] } ] }, { "startTime":1611288803278, "endTime":1611893603278, "sampleSet":[ { "dataCollectorId":"derived:com.huawei.continuous.calories.burnt:com.huawei.hwid:merged", "samplePoints":[] } ] }, { "startTime":1611288803278, "endTime":1611893603278, "sampleSet":[ { "dataCollectorId":"derived:com.huawei.instantaneous.heart_rate:com.huawei.hwid:merged", "samplePoints":[] } ] } ] }
```

HTTP response header showed “HTTP/1.1 200 OK”and the value of the x-health-app-privacy field is 2.

Could you give any info for x-health-app-privacy?

Is Austria (Europe) a supported region?  If so, is there any reason why I could not read the data from his account?

Answer (score 1):

1. the value of the x-health-app-privacy field in the HTTP response header is 2, which means that the user did not authorize the Health Kit to get data in the Sports Health App. Please refer to the below screenshots for users how to enable authorization.
2. for x-health-app-privacy, pls refer to below. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/latest- sampleset-0000001078273166-V5

ParameterTypeMandatory (M)/Optional (O)Description

[image]

Comment: This may be related to GDPR directive (a different legislation): https://huawei.eu/privacy-policy